# Have all the minor signs of Qiyamah been fulfilled?

Tags: hadith, day-of-judgement, surat-al-qiyamah

I've been hearing recently that all the minor signs of Qiyamah have been fulfilled with the exception of the Mahdi. Is this true? Are we really waiting for the Mahdi to come out at this point?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for the question.

Comment: I tend to say that this is a subjective question you may find people agreeing and others disagreeing. And only shi'a are waiting for the Mahdi to come others certainly expect him to come (as Imamah is the basis of their faith without it they are more or less lost and this imam should be from ahl al-Bayt) when the signs are fulfilled.

Answer (score -1):

No, the last minor sign of the day of judgement is when the mahdi appears and the mahdi has not appeared.

Comment: So the Mahdi is the ONLY minor sign left to be fulfilled?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works, and please cite external sources and [evidence](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/how-do-i-add-evidence-to-my-answer) and thoroughly answer the question asked.